# AngularJS ng-bind-html functionality inside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way how to do the same functionality as

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content"> </div>
```

inside a controller. Something like

```
var parsedString = ngBindHtml('<p>sjflkds</p>);
```

is there any way how to do something like this? Because I couldn't find in angular doc any function that would do the trick.

Comment: What is your primary goal which you want to achieve?

Comment: What would you expect `parsedString` to be in this case?